# How to replace arbitrary groups of symbols in javascript with one single symbol?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

So i have a String looking like so:

```
I+am++a+++great++coder
```

How do i delete my + in such a way, that only one space remains in each instance? I have tried using regex, but to no avail yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result either with splitting the string at every group of `+` and joining it with a single whitespace

```js
var str = 'I+am++a+++great++coder',
    res = str.split(/\++/g).join(' ');
    
    console.log(res);
```

or just replace every group of `+` with a single whitespace.

```js
var str = 'I+am++a+++great++coder',
    res = str.replace(/\++/g, ' ');
    
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: yea i already figuered it out by now. I thought it was more difficult. My regex had an error. thanks anyway! Very kind user ;)